# Problem with receiving ctypes `c_wchar_p` over python socket (python 3.7.7)

Tags: python, ctypes, python-sockets

(Windows 10, x64, PyCharm)

short story: I have a problem with `payload_in.event` and `payload_out.event` in the python server script. Both are from type `c_wchar_p` which is from `ctypes`.

long story:
I am working on a client and a server in python currently. They communicate over TCP/IP sockets on 127.0.01:6666. I am using the module Ctypes to send and receive a c-like struct. Everything works perfectly, I can send/recv arrays, integers, floats and work with them on both sides but I found out that there is a bug when printing `payload_in.event` and `payload_out.event` in the python server script, both of type `c_wchar_p`.

In the client script, I can access and print `payload_in.event` and `payload_out.event` perfectly ***but my server script can not even though the code is the same. . .

In the server script, printing `payload_in.event` and `payload_out.event` causes both programs to pause for 10 seconds or so and then the client console tells me that the connection to the server was closed.

Everything works fine if I comment out the printing of `payload_in.event` and `payload_out.event` in the python server script. I don't know how to fix this behaviour and would be glad if someone could help me out.

**beagleServer.py**

```py
import socket
from ctypes import *


class Struct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("id", c_uint32),  # 4B
                ("prio", c_uint32),  # 4B
                ("event", c_wchar_p),  # 8B
                ("data", c_float * 10)]  # 40B


def main():
    BUFFSIZE = sizeof(Struct)
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 6666

    beagleServer = socket.socket()
    beagleServer.bind((host, port))
    beagleServer.listen(1)

    print("Server is listening on " + host + ":" + str(port) + "!")
    client, clientAddress = beagleServer.accept()
    print("Connection from: " + str(clientAddress[0]) + ":" + str(clientAddress[1]))

    # receiving payload
    buffer = client.recv(BUFFSIZE)
    payload_in = Struct.from_buffer_copy(buffer)
    print("\nPayload of ", sizeof(payload_in), " Bytes has been received successfully: ", payload_in,
          "\nPayload.id: ", payload_in.id,
          "\nPayload.prio: ", payload_in.prio,
          "\nPayload.event: ", payload_in.event,
          "\nPayload.data: ", list(payload_in.data),
          "\nReceived buffer: ", buffer)

    # sending back payload
    payload_out = payload_in
    transferredBytes = client.send(payload_out)
    print("\nPayload of ", transferredBytes, " Bytes has been sent successfully: ", payload_out,
          "\nPayload.id: ", payload_out.id,
          "\nPayload.prio: ", payload_out.prio,
          "\nPayload.event: ", payload_out.event,
          "\nPayload.data: ", list(payload_out.data))

    print("Closing server socket!")
    client.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**beagleClient.py**

```py
import socket
from ctypes import *


class Struct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("id", c_uint32),  # 4B
                ("prio", c_uint32),  # 4B
                ("event", c_wchar_p),  # 8B
                ("data", c_float * 10)]  # 40B


beagleServer = ('127.0.0.1', 6666)
beagleClient = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
beagleClient.connect(beagleServer)
print("Connection with server has been established!")

# Creating the Struct
payload_out = Struct(390897,
                     0,
                     "activateMode1",
                     (3.12, 4.21, 1.23))
print("\nPayload of ", sizeof(payload_out), " Bytes has been created successfully: ", payload_out,
      "\nPayload.id: ", payload_out.id,
      "\nPayload.prio: ", payload_out.prio,
      "\nPayload.event: ", payload_out.event,
      "\nPayload.data: ", list(payload_out.data))

# Sending
bytesTransferred = beagleClient.send(payload_out)
print("\nPayload of ", bytesTransferred, " Bytes has been sent!")

# Receiving
BUFFSIZE = sizeof(Struct)
buffer = beagleClient.recv(BUFFSIZE)
payload_in = Struct.from_buffer_copy(buffer)
print("\nPayload of ", sizeof(payload_in), " Bytes has been received successfully: ", payload_in,
      "\nPayload.id: ", payload_in.id,
      "\nPayload.prio: ", payload_in.prio,
      "\nPayload.event: ", payload_in.event,
      "\nPayload.data: ", list(payload_in.data))

print("Closing the connection to ", beagleServer, "!")
beagleClient.close()
```

Comment: `c_wchar_p` is a *pointer* type.  Transferring this 64-bit value over the network does not magically grant the receiver the ability to read the data that is being pointed to, located somewhere in the memory space of the sending process.  You need to get the actual characters into the struct, rather than a pointer to them.

Comment: As jasonharper says... python has pointers. Your code blocks because it's trying to read the adress provided( might not even exist in the server mem space).

Comment: Thank you guys, now I am understanding it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Struct.event` is a pointer.  A pointer transmitted between two processes is just an address that has no meaning in the other process.  Use an array instead:

```
("event", c_wchar * 80)
```

It can still be initialized the same way, but you can't exceed the array size for the string transmitted.  Also `c_wchar` size varies between architectures, so you may want to use `c_char * 80` instead, and then encode/decode the string, e.g. `payload.event = 'some string'.encode()` (or just use a byte string: `b'some string'`).